# Допустимо ли выражение "занял первенство"

Tags: грамотная-речь, лексика, егэ

В шестом задании ЕГЭ, где надо исправить лексическую ошибку, попалось выражение "одержать первенство". В гугле искал, надо было заменить либо "первенство" на "победу", либо "одержать" на "завоевал". А что насчёт "занял первенство"?

Answer (score 3):

Для меня такой вариант выглядит неубедительно, поскольку "*занять*" можно *свободное место* (в частности - первое), а *первенство* - лишь частичный, смысловой синоним *первого места* в отдельных контекстах. Нельзя сказать, что первенство "было свободным", а затем было "занято". В прямом смысле слова *первенство* - **событие или факт, заключающийся в том, что кто-то стал первым в чём-то**. Первенства как *права называться (считаться) первым* можно **добиться**, это право (как Вы уже нашли) можно **завоевать**, но "занять" сочетается только с *первым местом*.